# How do you turn on the volume of a playing video in `AVPlayer` by pressing the volume up or down buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

How do you turn on the volume of a video playing with `AVPlayer` by pressing the volume up or down buttons if the iPhone is set on silent? (Set on silent with the physical silent button).

Some apps have this feature but by default it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In AppDelegate class**

When application did become active
Write a code in,

**applicationDidBecomeActive**

```
     do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
        } catch {
            print("AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback not work")
        }
```

When the application is about to move from active to inactive state.

**applicationWillResignActive**

```
     do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.soloAmbient)
        } catch {
            print("AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient not work")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You switch the audio session category to Playback. That overrides the silent switch.